# Tool to generate icons like the default dmg-icon with a custom icon on top in perspective

Tags: macos, mac, icons, dmg-image

I'm looking for a tool or template which generates icons like this default one:

[image]

With custom icons applied on top of it in the right perspective like here:

[image]

Comment: Nothing is going to beat Photoshop for this, especially when you are playing around with perspective transformations.  It would be even better to start off with making vector art in Illustrator and then exporting to Photoshop.

Comment: I did it with Photoshop. Wasn't too hard. The only part I didn't like was that when you copy the dmg-copy to the clipboard the transparency data is lost, so I had to cut it myself and re-apply the shadow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any tool to do it, but it was easy to do with the perspective transformation in Photoshop.